# Novel set in Roman ruled Britain

Tags: story-identification

Several years ago, I read a novel.  It was set in Britain at the twilight of the Roman rule there.  I think the author's last name was "White" or something similar.

IIRC, it was book 1 of a series, but I don't remember how many other books followed it.   I think it was published in the mid 90s or something. Perhaps earlier.

The main character is a blacksmith.  He used to be in the army.  He had an old war injury that prevented him from *ahem* performing with women.

> He finds a large amount of gold that someone (his father?) hid.  He eventually gets together with some other people to try and plan for life after Roman Rule fails its hold.
>  He gets some special ore that fell from the sky.  He uses it initially to make a statue of a woman.  Later, he forges it into a sword.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you want "[The Skystone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Skystone)" of the Camulod Chronicles, by Jack Whyte (1992).

It is basically a retelling of the origins of the Round Table and the Arthurian legend, as the main character is a soldier/blacksmith who recalls his tale in an autobiographical fashion. It is the times just after the Roman occupation, when Picts, Celts and others warred in the land, and this recounts the events that would eventually lead to the Round Table and what follows after.